# How to call an immutable ant target twice

Tags: ant

I have to run a pre-existing immutable target twice with different property values and have written a macrodef for it. I'm able to set the property value and run the macrodef twice but I do not know how to execute the target from within the macrodef. I've gone through many related posts and it seems that using antcall is my only option. Is there another way?

```
 Pre-existing, immutable target: unit-tests
 Main target called: release

 <macrodef name="unit-tests-macrodef">
    <attribute name="is-special-host"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Running target with @{is-special-host}" />
        <property name="jvmargs" value="${baseJvmArgs} -Dis.special.host=@{is-special-host}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="run-unit-tests">
    <unit-tests-macrodef is-special-host="false"/>
    <unit-tests-macrodef is-special-host="true"/>
</target>

<target name="release" depends="run-unit-tests" />
```

How do I ensure that `unit-tests-macrodef` runs `unit-tests` every time it is invoked?

Comment: Where is `unit-tests` target?

Comment: It is company specific target and is made available via our build system.

Comment: that is ok, where are you using it in the above xml?

Comment: I am not, because I don't know how to. I want to include it in the macrodef somehow.